# How to add app file to appium Desired Capabilities correctly?

Tags: java, android, appium, saucelabs

I used SauceLabs [example](https://saucelabs.com/resources/mobile-test-automation-in-java-with-appium)

```
   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
   capabilities.setCapability("BROWSER_NAME", "Android");
   capabilities.setCapability("VERSION", "4.4.2");
   capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Android Emulator");
   capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");

   //zip file containing your app to be tested
   capabilities.setCapability("app", "http://appium.s3.amazonaws.com/TestApp6.0.app.zip");

   driver = new RemoteWebDriver
   (new URL(MessageFormat.format("http://{0}:{1}@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub", 
   sauceUserName, sauceAccessKey)), capabilities);
```

And this is work perfectly fine. 
But when I downloaded zip with app and switched to local environment

```
capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());    
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

I got error from appium console:

> error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Bad app:
>   /home/.../appium/assets/TestApp6.0.app.zip. App paths need to
>   be absolute, or relative to the appium server install dir, or a URL to
>   compressed file, or a special app name. cause: App zip unzipped OK,
>   but we couldn't find a .app bundle in it. Make sure your archive
>   contains the .app package and nothing else

Comment: Could you please show the code where variable app (from app.getAbsolutePath()) is defined?

Comment: **Please unzip the .app file and provide the fully qualified .app file path to app path capability.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead of `RemoteWebDriver`: use `AndroidDriver`.
Also, if you run from `localhost` mention the IP address or just type `"localhost"`.

```
capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());    
driver = new AndroidDriver (new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Create a folder called `"app"` and place your testing Android app there.

Example code:

```
File filePath = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
File appDir = new File(filePath, "/app");
File app = new File(appDir, "yourapkfile.apk");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app and script needs to be in same directory, or you should specify complete path to .apk file in order for it work

Answer (score 0):

```
File app= new File("‪D:\\com.boondoggle.mortcalc-1.apk");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities= new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Redmi Note 3");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0.1");
capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
AndroidDriver driver= new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Comment: Please add english to explain what the code does. Thank you.